# How does ARRI saturation formula differ from the ASC-CDL spec?

Tags: color-correction

In the context of ASC-CDL, saturation is applied as:

```
luma = 0.2126*iR + 0.7152*iG + 0.0722*iB
oR = luma + saturation*(iR-luma)
oG = luma + saturation*(iG-luma)
oB = luma + saturation*(iB-luma)
```

However, in the [ARRI Look Files in the ALEXA Camera](http://www.arri.com/?eID=registration&file_uid=7760) whitepaper they say:

> Note: The ALEXA saturation parameter differs from the ASC CDL
>   saturation.

But they don't specify in what way, and I can't find that information anywhere.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it has something to do with the white point/primary chromaticities are Alexa Wide Gamut vs. Rec709.

http://www.arri.com/camera/alexa/learn/log_c_and_rec_709_video

Comment: Welcome to Video Production on Stack Exchange.  That made an interesting read.  Also enjoyed checking out your demo reel.